# hybridWebView page open another ContentPage from Javascript in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: javascript, c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently working in solution which Xamarin guys were provided on [this link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview/)
I basically want to user enter 4-digit PIN number and on a submit button, it should be transferred to Login page which is written in codebehind.
Here is my HTML with JS:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .phone-field {
        margin: 50px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .phone-input {
        width: 13px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 16px !important;
        height: 1.75em;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
        background: transparent;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
        margin-right: 2px;
        margin-left: 2px;
    }

    [placeholder]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        transition: opacity 0.5s 0.0s ease;
        opacity: 0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="phone-field">
    <form>
        <input class="phone-input" id="one" name="phone-input" size="1" maxlength="1" placeholder="">
        <input class="phone-input" id="two" name="phone-input" size="1" maxlength="1" placeholder="">
        <input class="phone-input" id="three" name="phone-input" size="1" maxlength="1" placeholder="">
        <input class="phone-input" id="four" name="phone-input" size="1" maxlength="1" placeholder="">
        <input type="submit" onclick="javascript:invokeCSCode($('#one').val()+$('#two').val()+$('#three').val()+$('#four').val());" value="submit">
    </form>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('body').on('keyup', 'input.phone-input', function () {
            var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
            var inputs = $('input.phone-input');
            if (($(this).val().length === this.size) && key != 32) {
                inputs.eq(inputs.index(this) + 1).focus();
            }
            if (key == 8 || key == 46) {
                var indexNum = inputs.index(this);
                if (indexNum != 0) {
                    inputs.eq(inputs.index(this)).val('').focus();
                    inputs.eq(inputs.index(this) - 1).focus();
                }
            }

        });
    });

</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.inputs').keyup(function () {
            if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
                $(this).next('.inputs').focus();
            }
        });
        function log(str) {
            $('#result').text($('#result').text() + " " + str);
        }

        function invokeCSCode(data) {
            try {
                log("Sending Data:" + data);
                invokeCSharpAction(data);
            }
            catch (err) {
                log(err);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I see a line where is been called C# (throgh JSBridge):

```
hybridWebView.RegisterAction (data => DisplayAlert ("Alert", "Hello " + data, "OK"));
```

and I tried instead of this line to put:

```
hybridWebView.RegisterAction(data => new PageNext());
```

But it doesn't work.

Basically, I need to call new page from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try pushing your new PageNext page onto the navigation stack, like so:

```
hybridWebView.RegisterAction(data => Navigation.PushAsync (new PageNext()));
```

or you could try using `Navigation.PushModalAsync (new PageNext());` in RegisterAction instead if your page should be displayed like a modal.

Comment: now I just got exit from an application. For some reason I cannot debug code on this xamarin solution (probably because it contains JS..)

Comment: What exception are you getting? Why can't you debug code? If you post some more details than "exit from an application" I might be able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
hybridWebView.RegisterAction(data =>  tonextpage() );

void tonextpage()
    {
        MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new nextPage());
        });
  }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.